# Sound through headphones but no sound through internal speakers

Tags: sound, headphones, speakers

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04. I am dual booting with windows 8.1. I am having the problem of only getting sound through headphones and not through my internal speakers in my laptop. When I go to the sound setting it only gives me the option of playing sound through my headphones and not through my internal speakers. I have a Dell Inspiron 15z. Thanks for any help.